# How can I defined a callback for jquery .trigger()?

Tags: jquery, callback

I have this code which is in the middle of a loop:

```
$('input[name="field_add_more"]').trigger('mousedown');
 mycustomfunction();
```

But the `mycustomfunction();` is not always executed. I need to move this into a callback for `.trigger()` but I cannot figure out how to do this, and there is no documentation for it on jQuery. Can this be done?

I really don't want to have to use a setTimeout on it. Also it HAS to be a `.trigger()` for it to work. Binding a `'click'` does not work.

Any ideas how I can do this? I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
$('input[name="field_add_more"]').trigger('mousedown', function() {
  mycustomfunction();
});
```

Comment: So you want to trigger the mousedown event and then call your function after that event has been handled?

Comment: Yes, call my event AFTER the mousedown event has fully completed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name="field_add_more"]').mousedown(mycustomfunction).mousedown();
```

Answer (score 2):

`.trigger()` fires the event you put. so the event need to be listened in the same manner as usual.

so use before you fire it.

```
$('input[name="field_add_more"]').mousedown(mycustomfunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

To Trigger the mousedown event use

```
$('input[name="field_add_more"]').trigger('mousedown','mycustomfunction');
```

To bind the mousedown use

```
$('input[name="field_add_more"]').bind('mousedown', function(e,callback) 
{
     ....
     var fn = window[callback];
    if(typeof fn === 'function')  fn();
});
```